# Like button: can like, not share

Tags: facebook, button, share, facebook-like

I have the fb like button on my website. When I click `like` the site is liked but when I add a personalized message to the share nothing appears on my wall. The number of likes is increased at first, but then I reload the website the number of likes is returned to its previous number.

If you want to check what happens: http://www.koosvandeput.nl/heren/elektrische-fietsen/gazelle/gazelle-orange-pure-innergy-2013-82265.html

Use the like button to the right of 'deel fiets'

Does anyone know why this is happening? It happens in all browsers and operating systems.

Comment: Can you share your custom code with us for the personalized message please?

Comment: Well, its working fine. Posted on my wall and the count remains.

Comment: @sahil: May I ask which browser uou use? Because when I use Google Chrome or Firefox I can not get it to work. And with me just about everyone here at the company, and anyone I know in The Netherlands...

Comment: I tested in chrome, the post is still active on my wall.

Comment: I see that it has been shared. Strange that I can't get it to work than. And with me everyone I know...

Comment: I have found out that the problem only occurs in Linux. There is no problem when using Windows or OSX. The only browser that works OK in Linux with the facebook like button is Opera.

Comment: It does work on my computer and im using Debian 6.0 linux with google chrome.

Comment: The exact opposite seems to happen to me, not just one my website but many websites. Facebook changed how their buttons work recently...